# Admin grid container not loading

Tags: grid

First of all I'm trying to load grid container and show container heading. My block file is working fine.
Container path is Super->Awesome->Block->Adminhtml->Awesome.php which contains

```
<?php
class Super_Awesome_Block_Adminhtml_Awesome extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'super_awesome';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_awesome';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('super_awesome')->__('Manage');
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

layout file super_awesome.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_example_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="super_awesome/adminhtml_awesome" name="super_awesome"></block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_example_index>
</layout>
```

If I echo something inside `public function __construct()`, it's showing content but on adding proper `__contruct()` method as above it's showing a blank page.
Do I need to add internal block(Grid.php) also, then my container text will appear? Container block Awesome.php should be changed to Grid.php?

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Super_Awesome>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Super_Awesome>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <super_awesome before="Mage_Adminhtml">Super_Awesome</super_awesome>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <super_awesome>
                    <file>super_awesome.xml</file>
                </super_awesome>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <super_awesome>
                <class>Super_Awesome_Block</class>
            </super_awesome>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <super_awesome>
                <class>Super_Awesome_Helper</class>
            </super_awesome>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Do you have your `Super_Awesome_Block_Adminhtml_Awesome_Grid.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are adding in your __construct method sets the details for the internal block that I think you are missing.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'super_awesome';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_awesome';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('super_awesome')->__('Manage');
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Those settings are used in the parents _prepareLayout() method as below.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->setChild( 'grid',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
        $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

For you this bit of code will end up as

```
  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('super_awesome/adminhtml_awesome_grid');
```

Which means you need to create the block `Super_Awesome_Block_Adminhtml_Awesome_Grid` which should extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`.

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Poll_Grid` could be used as an example for this missing grid block.